# How to parametrize a C++ template for a number system output operator?

Tags: c++, templates

For practice reasons I'd like to write a template class that I can use to print decimal numbers in various other number systems (like hex or octal).

In principle, I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
int main() {
    Num<hex> k_hex = 20;
    Num<Oct> k_oct = 20;
    std::cout << k_hex << std::endl;  // "0x14"
    std::cout << k_oct << std::endl;  // "0o24"
}
```

My attempt is to make a template for the `Num` class, where I can provide a type for a number system:

```
template<typename B>
struct Num {
    int i;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const int& i) {
        return os << std::template B << i;
    }
};
```

My question is now, how do I need to build up the number-type classes? I guess they somehow need to return a stream manipulator (for the `os << std::template B << i` part).

So perhaps like this but I'm not sure what to return:

```
struct hex {
    using returnType = typename std::function<std::ostream& (std::ostream& os, int i)>;

    template<typename base>
    static returnType base = [](std::ostream& os, int i) {
        return os << std::ios::base << i;
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you examined the code in the implementation of the C++ standard library you're using to see how they implement things like std::hex?

Comment: What about something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/bb6TYG)? Or [this](https://godbolt.org/z/3E7v8G)?

Comment: @Evg In your second variant, am I seeing this correctly that you are passing a `std::hex` manipulator as the template specialization type? Template parameters can be *functions*?

Comment: @TMOTTM, template non-type parameters can be function pointers.